# PHP Server REQUEST_URI Ignores Single Character After Last Slash In URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I am trying to get current page URL using PHP and somehow it is not working properly. Here is the code that I am using

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')   
     $url = "https://";   
else  
     $url = "http://";   
$url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   
$url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
  
echo $url;
```

Now I pass a URL like `https://example.com/a` even with `/a` at the end of URL I am still getting

> `https://example.com`

and **NOT**

> `https://example.com/a`

It is echoing correct URL when URL contains more than one characters after last slash like `https://example.com/aa`

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Unrelated but you could likely use protocol-independent URL instead of `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on'`. Have you looked at what `$_SERVER` has for the indices you are using when loading? Are any rewrite rules in affect?

Comment: Hi no, I am not using any rewite rule

Comment: What are server values when loaded? `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTPS'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

Comment: What do you mean  by server values? how can I get them?

Comment: They meant you should do the var_dump as shown, and share the results ...

Comment: "no, I am not using any rewite rule" - How is your PHP being called if you are not using rewrite rules in `.htaccess`? (You have also tagged the question `.htaccess`?)